# send restful request from Angular 2

Tags: javascript, java, angular, rest

I have an Angular login app and also I have a restful webservice in java which should search for an user in database . Please, help me how to send request from angular to this service. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It may be better to check the Angular docs for something like this. Have a read of https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I suggest you to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a service in angular which will serve as a connector between your webservice and angular app. For creating service.ts follow [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#services).
In your service.ts add codes like

```
searchService() {
    const url = 'yourURL' + 'your api url';
    return this.http.get(url).map((res: Response) => res.json()); 
}//for get request



searchService(data) {
      const url = 'yourURL' + 'your api url';
      return this.http.post(url, data, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }//for post request
```

Now call this service function in your .ts file after you import service.ts into your required .ts file like:

```
callSearchService() {
    this._service.searchService(data).subscribe(searchData => {
        console.log(searchData);//your API response
    });
}
```

This much should help your, for intracting your angular app to your database.
Please ask if you got any query.

Comment: this is my service 
`searchUser(fname:string,lname:string){
      const url='localhost:8080/SearchApp-1.0/fname/lname';
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
    }`
this is how i call from .ts file
`this.searchService.searchUser(this.firstName,this.lastName).subscribe(searchData=>{
        console.log(searchData);
       }) }`
and it shoud work on onClick event, but when i click button, i get this error "zone.js:2969 Failed to load localhost:8080/SearchApp-1.0/fname/lname.." What should i do?

Comment: "zone.js:2969 Failed to load localhost:8080/SearchApp-1.0/fname/lname: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."